# What do you call this job in English?

Tags: synonyms

I'm asking for a bit of advice for my kid's summer homework :-)

I'd need to find out "what are their jobs" based on the below objects. I'm missing the last one, but I assume it starts with "T" as reading it vertically should be a job as well:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"Teacher" - The picture is are stereotypical grade school / ["composition" notebooks](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=composition%20notebook&qs=n&form=QBIR&sp=-1&pq=composition%20notebook&sc=8-20&sk=&cvid=C88A1B5DFD20432884CC24F84DAB82C3). So a teacher asks of them, reads them, or is around them (plural) (whereas a student might just have 1 individual one).